# ¿Cómo Activar y Desactivar Botón?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tengo el siguiente problema:

***1)*** Cuando llamo a la función `function add(button)` el botón "Agregar" se debe desactivar, hasta el momento funciona ok, el problema se inicia en la tabla `<table id="target">....` al momento de eliminar un item el botón se debe activar nuevamente.

***2)*** El botón `<button id="run" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>` se debe activar o desactivar solo cuando la o las celdas `QtyValue` sean mayor a 0.

Éste es mi código:

```js
function add(button) {
  var row = button.parentNode.parentNode;
  var cells = row.querySelectorAll('td:not(:last-of-type)');
  button.disabled = true;
  addToCartTable(cells);
}

function remove() {
  var row = this.parentNode.parentNode;
  document.querySelector('#target tbody')
    .removeChild(row);
  var celda = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').text();
  var botones = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');
  for (var i = 0; i < botones.length; i++) {
    botones[i].addEventListener('click', (function (i) {
      return function () {
        this.disable = false;
      };
    })(i), false);
  }
};

function addToCartTable(cells) {
  var registro = cells[0].innerText;
  var name = cells[2].innerText;
  var price = cells[3].innerText;
  var newRow = document.createElement('tr');
  
  newRow.setAttribute('data-price', price.substring(0));
  newRow.appendChild(createCell(registro));
  newRow.appendChild(createCell(name));
  newRow.appendChild(createCell(price));
  newRow.appendChild(createCell('1'));
  newRow.appendChild(createCell(price));

  var cellInputQty = createCell();
  cellInputQty.appendChild(createInputQty());
  newRow.appendChild(cellInputQty);

  var cellRemoveBtn = createCell();
  cellRemoveBtn.appendChild(createRemoveBtn())
  newRow.appendChild(cellRemoveBtn);

  document.querySelector('#target tbody').appendChild(newRow);
}

function createInputQty() {
  var inputQty = document.createElement('input');
  inputQty.type = 'number';
  inputQty.required = 'true';
  inputQty.className = 'form-control'
  inputQty.min = 1; // mínimo un producto
  inputQty.onchange = onQtyChange;
  inputQty.value = 0;
  return inputQty;
}

function createRemoveBtn() {
  var btnRemove = document.createElement('button');
  btnRemove.className = 'btn btn-xs btn-danger';
  btnRemove.onclick = remove;
  btnRemove.innerText = 'Eliminar';
  return btnRemove;
}

function createCell(text) {
  var td = document.createElement('td');
  if (text) {
    td.innerText = text;
  }
  return td;
}

function onQtyChange(e) {
  var row = this.parentNode.parentNode;
  var cellPrice = row.querySelector('td:nth-child(3)');
  var prevPrice = Number(row.getAttribute('data-price'));
  var newQty = Number(this.value);
  var total = prevPrice * newQty;

  var QtyValue = row.querySelector('td:nth-child(4)');
  QtyValue.innerText = newQty;
  cellPrice.innerText = '$' + total;
  if (QtyValue > 0) {
    document.getElementById('run').disabled = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('run').disabled = true;
  }
}

function createFormData(info) {
  jsonObject = {};
  var datos = 'datos';
  jsonObject[datos] = info;
  return jsonObject;
}

$('#run').click(function () {
  var table = $('#target').tableToJSON();
  console.log(JSON.stringify(createFormData(table)));
  console.log('se inicia el ajax');
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/WebMethod.aspx/SendMail",
    data: JSON.stringify({ datos: JSON.stringify(createFormData(table)) }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: OnSuccess,
    failure: function (response) {
      alert(response.d);
    }
  });
  alert(JSON.stringify(table));
});

function OnSuccess(response) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
  if (response.d == "True") {
    alert('Email Enviado Correctamente');
  } else {
    alert('Fallo en envio');
  }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  document.getElementById('run').disabled = true;
});

$(document).ready(function () {
  document.getElementById('run').disabled = true;
  $('#source').DataTable({
    "language": {
      "sProcessing": "Procesando...",
      "sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
      "sZeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
      "sEmptyTable": "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
      "sInfo": "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
      "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
      "sInfoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
      "sInfoPostFix": "",
      "sSearch": "Buscar:",
      "sUrl": "",
      "sInfoThousands": ",",
      "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
      "oPaginate": {
        "sFirst": "Primero",
        "sLast": "Último",
        "sNext": "Siguiente",
        "sPrevious": "Anterior"
      },
      "oAria": {
        "sSortAscending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
        "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#target td {
  /* para centrado vertical de contenido */
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#target tr > *:nth-child(4) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.adt.com.ar/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://lightswitch05.github.io/table-to-json/javascripts/jquery.tabletojson.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<form id="form1">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <HeaderTemplate>
      <table id="source" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Código</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Precio</th>
            <th>Acciones</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
          <tr>
            <td>1000</td>
            <td>001</td>
            <td>Producto 1</td>
            <td>1500</td>
            <td>
              <button onclick="add(this)" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" id="btn">
                Agregar
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
          <tr>
            <td>2000</td>
            <td>002</td>
            <td>Producto 2</td>
            <td>2500</td>
            <td>
              <button onclick="add(this)" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" id="btn">
                Agregar
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
          <tr>
            <td>3000</td>
            <td>003</td>
            <td>Producto 3</td>
            <td>3500</td>
            <td>
              <button onclick="add(this)" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" id="btn">
                Agregar
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
          <tr>
            <td>4000</td>
            <td>004</td>
            <td>Producto 4</td>
            <td>4500</td>
            <td>
              <button onclick="add(this)" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" id="btn">
                Agregar
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
  </div>
  
  <button id="run" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="target" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Código</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Precio</th>
          <th>qty</th>
          <th>unit</th>
          <th>Cantidad</th>
          <th>Acciones</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</form>
```

¿Alguna idea que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Parece que el código que compartes no es el generado, sino el código en .net (además de que hay mucho JS que realmente no afecta al problema y sólo crea "ruido"). Aunque se puede ver el problema, lo ideal sería que compartieses el código generado y lo mínimo para ver el problema. Te recomiendo que leas cómo crear un [mcve] en el Centro de Ayuda.

Comment: Es el código completo. Adapté las tablas para que muestre información ya que viene desde una BD.

Comment: Completo no significa que tengas que poner todo el código que tienes. Poner demasiado código crea ruido y hace más difícil encontrar el problema (por eso la importancia de que sea mínimo). El código que pones está bien en el sentido que permite ver el problema, pero podría quitarse bastante código (de hecho se ha hecho en un par de ediciones, aunque se podría hacer aún más) que no ayuda a identificar o definir el problema.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Voy a intentar cambiar tu código lo menos posible, entonces para los problemas que describes:

- El primer problema se debe a cómo estás intentando habilitar el botón: lo estás asociando a un evento `click` que nunca va a ocurrir porque el botón está deshabilitado y no se puede pulsar. Además, parece no haber una manera directa de asociar esa fila en la tabla "target" con la tabla "source", por lo que deberías tratar de leer el código y entonces activar el botón que esté en la misma fila que el código ese. Algo como esto:

  ```
  ....
  var botones = document.querySelectorAll('#source .btn');
  for (var i = 0; i < botones.length; i++) {
      if ($(botones[i]).closest("tr").find("td:eq(0)").text() == celda) {
          botones[i].disabled = false;
      }
  }
  ....
  ```
- El segundo problema se debe a que en la función `onQtyChange`, estás comprobando el valor de `QtyValue` que la celda que contiene el valor (por lo que su valor será `<td>1</td>`, siendo el número la cantidad seleccionada), cuando realmente deberías estar comprobado `newQty` que es el valor contenido en el campo:

  ```
  ....
  if (newQty > 0) {
      document.getElementById('run').disabled = false;
  } else {
      document.getElementById('run').disabled = true;
  }
  ....
  ```

Una vez solucionados esos dos puntos, el código quedará así y funcionará:

```js
function add(button) {
  var row = button.parentNode.parentNode;
  var cells = row.querySelectorAll('td:not(:last-of-type)');
  button.disabled = true;
  addToCartTable(cells);
}

function remove() {
  var row = this.parentNode.parentNode;
  document.querySelector('#target tbody')
    .removeChild(row);
  var celda = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').text();
  var botones = document.querySelectorAll('#source .btn');
  for (var i = 0; i < botones.length; i++) {
    if ($(botones[i]).closest("tr").find("td:eq(0)").text() == celda) {
        botones[i].disabled = false;
    }
  }
};

function addToCartTable(cells) {
  var registro = cells[0].innerText;
  var name = cells[2].innerText;
  var price = cells[3].innerText;
  var newRow = document.createElement('tr');
  
  newRow.setAttribute('data-price', price.substring(0));
  newRow.appendChild(createCell(registro));
  newRow.appendChild(createCell(name));
  newRow.appendChild(createCell(price));
  newRow.appendChild(createCell('1'));
  newRow.appendChild(createCell(price));

  var cellInputQty = createCell();
  cellInputQty.appendChild(createInputQty());
  newRow.appendChild(cellInputQty);

  var cellRemoveBtn = createCell();
  cellRemoveBtn.appendChild(createRemoveBtn())
  newRow.appendChild(cellRemoveBtn);

  document.querySelector('#target tbody').appendChild(newRow);
}

function createInputQty() {
  var inputQty = document.createElement('input');
  inputQty.type = 'number';
  inputQty.required = 'true';
  inputQty.className = 'form-control'
  inputQty.min = 1; // mínimo un producto
  inputQty.onchange = onQtyChange;
  inputQty.value = 0;
  return inputQty;
}

function createRemoveBtn() {
  var btnRemove = document.createElement('button');
  btnRemove.className = 'btn btn-xs btn-danger';
  btnRemove.onclick = remove;
  btnRemove.innerText = 'Eliminar';
  return btnRemove;
}

function createCell(text) {
  var td = document.createElement('td');
  if (text) {
    td.innerText = text;
  }
  return td;
}

function onQtyChange(e) {
  var row = this.parentNode.parentNode;
  var cellPrice = row.querySelector('td:nth-child(3)');
  var prevPrice = Number(row.getAttribute('data-price'));
  var newQty = Number(this.value);
  var total = prevPrice * newQty;

  var QtyValue = row.querySelector('td:nth-child(4)');
  QtyValue.innerText = newQty;
  cellPrice.innerText = '$' + total;
  if (newQty > 0) {
    document.getElementById('run').disabled = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('run').disabled = true;
  }

}

function createFormData(info) {
  jsonObject = {};
  var datos = 'datos';
  jsonObject[datos] = info;
  return jsonObject;
}

$('#run').click(function () {
  var table = $('#target').tableToJSON();
  console.log(JSON.stringify(createFormData(table)));
  console.log('se inicia el ajax');
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/WebMethod.aspx/SendMail",
    data: JSON.stringify({ datos: JSON.stringify(createFormData(table)) }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: OnSuccess,
    failure: function (response) {
      alert(response.d);
    }
  });
  alert(JSON.stringify(table));
});

function OnSuccess(response) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
  if (response.d == "True") {
    alert('Email Enviado Correctamente');
  } else {
    alert('Fallo en envio');
  }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  document.getElementById('run').disabled = true;
});

$(document).ready(function () {
  document.getElementById('run').disabled = true;
  $('#source').DataTable({
    "language": {
      "sProcessing": "Procesando...",
      "sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
      "sZeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
      "sEmptyTable": "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
      "sInfo": "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
      "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
      "sInfoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
      "sInfoPostFix": "",
      "sSearch": "Buscar:",
      "sUrl": "",
      "sInfoThousands": ",",
      "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
      "oPaginate": {
        "sFirst": "Primero",
        "sLast": "Último",
        "sNext": "Siguiente",
        "sPrevious": "Anterior"
      },
      "oAria": {
        "sSortAscending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
        "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#target td {
  /* para centrado vertical de contenido */
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#target tr > *:nth-child(4) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.adt.com.ar/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://lightswitch05.github.io/table-to-json/javascripts/jquery.tabletojson.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<form id="form1">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <HeaderTemplate>
      <table id="source" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Código</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Precio</th>
            <th>Acciones</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
          <tr>
            <td>1000</td>
            <td>001</td>
            <td>Producto 1</td>
            <td>1500</td>
            <td>
              <button onclick="add(this)" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" id="btn">
                Agregar
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
          <tr>
            <td>2000</td>
            <td>002</td>
            <td>Producto 2</td>
            <td>2500</td>
            <td>
              <button onclick="add(this)" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" id="btn">
                Agregar
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
          <tr>
            <td>3000</td>
            <td>003</td>
            <td>Producto 3</td>
            <td>3500</td>
            <td>
              <button onclick="add(this)" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" id="btn">
                Agregar
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
          <tr>
            <td>4000</td>
            <td>004</td>
            <td>Producto 4</td>
            <td>4500</td>
            <td>
              <button onclick="add(this)" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" id="btn">
                Agregar
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
  </div>
  
  <button id="run" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="target" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Código</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Precio</th>
          <th>qty</th>
          <th>unit</th>
          <th>Cantidad</th>
          <th>Acciones</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Como solución alternativa, podrías añadir clases a las filas para que tengan como clase el mismo código que el producto que contienen. De ese modo se simplificaría bastante el código JS y sería más sencillo asociar los registros de las dos tablas (ya sea poniendo clases también a la tabla "target" o usando un "data-id" en el botón de Eliminar)